# Using wxPython's wx.TextCtrl blocks out rest of form

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython to build forms. I am new to wxpython. My first form opens correctly and when you press the Travel Advisory button the second form opens. This is where the users will enter information. When I use this line of code to be able to enter text:
self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(100, 145), size=(140,-1))
it will obliterate everything else on the form. Comment the line out and the form is good. I am having trouble figuring this out and cannot seem to find a good answer on the web. Here is my code so far. Any help would be great.

```
import wx

# varialbes
title = 'Advisory Form'
closuretypeList = ['is closed ', 'is open', 'closed for season ', 'open for season ']
stateList = ['Alabama','Alaska']
analystList = []
dotPhoneList = []
dotWebList = []

class formMS(wx.Frame):
    #formMS is main switchboard
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        # create form
        super(formMS, self).__init__(parent,title=title,size=(225, 350))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        font1 = wx.Font(11, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, True)

        #add static labels
        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "FORMS", (55, 15))
        text1.SetFont(font1)

        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "REPORTS", (55, 110))
        text2.SetFont(font1)

        #Form buttons
        self.buttonTAForm = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_OPEN, label="Travel Advisory", pos = (55, 40))
        self.buttonTAForm.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.buttonTAForm)

        self.buttonDOTForm = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_ANY, label="DOT Contacts", pos = (55, 75))

        #Report Buttons
        self.buttonTARep = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_ANY, label="TA Report", pos = (55, 140))
        self.buttonDOTContactRep = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_ANY, label="DOT Contacts", pos = (55, 175))

        #cancel button
        self.buttonCancel = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_CANCEL, label="Close",pos = (55,225))
        self.buttonCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseMe)
        self.buttonCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnClick(self, event):
        secondWindow = formTAN(self)
        secondWindow.Show()

    def OnCloseMe(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

class formTAN(wx.Frame):

    #formTAN is Travel Advisory Notice Form
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # create form
        super(formTAN, self).__init__(parent,size=(550, 650))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        font1 = wx.Font(11, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, True)
        font2 = wx.Font(9, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False)

        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(100, 145), size=(140,-1))

        #Label Panel
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "TRAVEL ADVISORY FORM", (170, 15))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font1)

        #Clears form to create a new record
        self.buttonNew = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_ANY, label="New Record", pos = (55, 40))

        #Exits Form
        self.buttonCancel = wx.Button(panel,id=wx.ID_CANCEL, label="All Clear/Exit",pos = (380,40))
        self.buttonCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseMe)

        #Selects type of closure
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Closure Type", (10, 85))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        self.choClosureType = wx.Choice(panel,-1, (100, 85),choices=closuretypeList)
        # self.choClosureType.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.OnSelect)

        #Drop down list of states/provinces
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "State", (10, 115))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        self.choStateType = wx.Choice(panel,-1, (100, 115),choices=stateList)
        # self.choClosureType.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.OnSelect)

        #Enter strip map number
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Strip #:", (250, 115))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        # self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(100, 145), size=(140, -1))
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.EvtText, self.editname)
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.EvtChar, self.editname)

        #Enter route name
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Road Name:", (10, 145))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)

        #Enter area in question
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "To / From:", (250, 145))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)

        #Extra Details
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Description:", (10, 175))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        # self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(100, 170), size=(400, 150), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        #Dot Phone number
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "DOT Phone:", (10, 275))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        self.choDotPhoneType = wx.Choice(panel,-1, (100, 275),choices=dotPhoneList)

        #DOT websites
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "DOT Website:", (250, 275))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        self.choDotWebType = wx.Choice(panel,-1, (350, 275),choices=dotWebList)

        #Analyst list
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Analyst:", (10, 305))
        self.lblname.SetFont(font2)
        self.choAnalystType = wx.Choice(panel,-1, (100, 305),choices=analystList)

    def OnCloseMe(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    formMS(None, title='Travel Advisory')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the # create form part of your class formTAN

```
self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(100, 145), size=(140,-1))
```

is parented to self, it needs parenting to the panel that is a child of self

```
self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(100, 145), size=(140,-1))
```

The #Extra Details part of your class formTAN

```
self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(100, 170), size=(400, 150),
    style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
```

is also parented to self so also needs parenting to panel, and its height 150 is making it cover other controls,
changing the height to 100 sorts this out.

```
self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(100, 170), size=(400, 100),
    style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
```